# Solution of differential equation of a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all real valued $C^1$ solutions for the equation $xy'(x)+y(x)=x$, for $x \in (-1,1)$.

My query is: can I put $x=0$ in the general solution of that differential equation, as $x=0$ is well within the given range $(-1,1)$ for $x$?

I found a general solution of: $2yx=x^2+c$. If I put $x=0$ we will obtain a solution of $y=x/2$.

The given question asks for *all* real-valued $C^1$ solutions.

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhh what?

Comment: do you mean whether $a_0$ will also be a root of the derivative of the function?

Comment: could you please explain yourself, the question stated like that is impossible to understand.

Comment: @ErnestoIglesias I have edited the question

Comment: At [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find tips on how to format math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
x y' + y&=x \\
\implies (xy)' &= x\\
\implies xy &= \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C \\
\implies y&=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{C}{x}
\end{align}
So please be aware of letting $x=0$.In fact I do not like your range beign set as $x \in (-1, +1)$ either.